# Can any one tell what is the error in this Linked list creation

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

### Inside insert function head is not updating.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct node {

    int data;
    struct node* next;
}*head = NULL;


void insert(struct node* head, int data) {

    struct node * newNode ;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head =newNode;
        
    }
    else {
        struct node* current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        //newNode->next = NULL;
        current->next = newNode;
    }
    
}


void display(struct node * head) {

    struct node* current = head;
    while (current) {
        cout << current->data<<endl;
    }
}


int main()
{

    insert(head, 5);
    insert(head, 6);
    insert(head, 56);
    insert(head, 65);
    insert(head, 885);
    insert(head, 66);
    insert(head, 00);

    display(head);

}
```

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Where you are storing your pointer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is your `head` outside the scope of your function is still `NULL`. You have to define a pointer to this `head` in order to update it. Apart from that it is required to dynamically allocate memory for the `newNode`.

```
void insert(struct node** head, int data) {

    struct node * newNode = new node() ;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        struct node* current = *head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        //newNode->next = NULL;
        current->next = newNode;
    }      
}
```

From `main()` call `insert` function as: `insert(&head, 5);`.

Another problem in your code is in `display` function, you're not updating `current` to `current->next`.

```
while (current) {
    cout << current->data << endl;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: And: Do not forget to delete the newed memory . . .